# How to destroy all previous activities when I start activity from custom shortcut?

Tags: android, android-activity, shortcut

**My steps:**

1. launcher shortcut start Activity **A**;
2. click **HOME** button;
3. custom shortcut start Activity **B**;
4. click **BACK** button - shows me Activity **A**.

But When I click custom shortcut I want that all my old activities **closed**. How can I do this?

**Manifest:**

```
activity A: android:launchMode="singleTop"
activity B: android:launchMode="singleTop" and android:exported="true"
```

**java:**

```
private void setShortCut() {
  Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), A.class);
  shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "test");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, ((BitmapDrawable)imgLogo.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
  intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
  sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: did you try android:noHistory="true"?

Comment: `launchMode="singleTop"` is working correctly. You have only a single instance of ActivityA and a single instance of ActivityB. You can't get the behaviour you want using `singleTop`.

Comment: @Kgrover if I'll set `android:noHistory="true"`, then `finish()` method will be execute every time for ActivityA. Not only when I start my app from custom shortcut.

Comment: @David Wasser, you are absolutely right. Thanks for explanation!!!
Do you have any ideas on destroing all previous activities?

Comment: you do not want 4. click BACK button - shows me Activity A right?

Comment: @Hoan Nguyen, yes. **1.** I want to see my home screen **2.** I want that all my old activities closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
activity A: android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
activity B: android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" and android:exported="true"
```

From the official document at    http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#finish

"Whether or not an existing instance of the activity should be shut down (finished) whenever the user again launches its task (chooses the task on the home screen) — "true" if it should be shut down, and "false" if not. The default value is "false"."

Comment: In this case on click **launcher-shortcut** I'll always see ActivityA. Not only after **custom-shortcut** click. _I want that all my old activities closed_ only after _custom-shortcut start Activity B_.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you have your custom-shortcut also start `ActivityA`, but pass an additional **extra** in the `Intent`. In `ActivityA.onNewIntent()` and in `ActivityA.onCreate()` you can check if the extra is present, and if so, launch `ActivityB` and call `finish()`. This should give you the behaviour you want.

For example, add this when you create the custom shortcut:

```
shortcutIntent.putExtra("customShortcut", true);
```

and put this code in `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()` of `ActivityA`:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("customShortcut")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity();
    finish();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Now I am using this technique. But user always see **ActivityA** a second wile **ActivityB** launching. 
So I wanted to find a way how to close all my old activities.

Comment: Well, if ActivityB takes that long to launch, then closing all your old activities may not help. If you remove 'launchMode="singleTop"` from your root activity and also remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` from the launch intents, this will cause `ActivityA` to be recreated when it launches. Maybe that will help.